# Open file in Adobe Acrobat then save back to website with Acrobat save button

Tags: pdf, annotations, acrobat

I'm sure this isn't possible but figured I'd check --

Using Adobe, is there a way to open a PDF from a webpage. The PDF would then be viewed and marked up if necessary.

Then, the user would click the built-in Adobe 'SAVE' button and the pdf would be sent back to the server.

I'm sure it's a long shot that this is built into adobe, but we need annotation ability in a web-based app and the tools I've seen thus far are either extremely expensive or not very good or both.

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Have you found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Acrobat alone. Perhaps if the file was in SharePoint or a WebDav server, it might allow you to save it back to the server. Adobe probably offer something that will provide the functionality in their [LiveCycle product suite](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/), but it is probably too expensive for you.

Do need to do further edits on the document? If not, you could possibly rasterize the documents and use some sort of web image editing tool to enable browser-based editing. Save the user's changes to a new PDF or image file. You might want to take a look at [Atalasoft's](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/thinclient/) products.